# How to make ssh connection to LXC container by its name?

Tags: ssh, lxc

Is it possible to make ssh connection to lxc container by its name?

I have been using IP addresses but then I though how easy it would be to use `ssh test01` (here `test01` being container name) instead of remembering its IP address, or starting the container and looking its IP.

Comment: Do you have a LAN set up for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `~/.ssh/config`, with contents:

```
Host test01
    Hostname 192.168.3.1
```

Then `chmod` it to 0600 and enjoy.  You can add any `ssh_config(5)` options there (changing the remote username is a particularly useful one), and youy can have as many `Host` sections as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Get a dns server up and running. [unbound](https://unbound.net/) is pretty simple and allows for private authoritative zones.